# Apple Numbers: Convert Date format M/D/YY or D/M/YY to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: date, formula, date-conversion, apple-numbers, apple-numbers-formula

Note: I had this question, couldn't find an answer and can provide the answer myself. I hope this can be used by others too.

Using Apple Numbers, how can I convert the date format of `M/D/YY` to `YYYY-MM-DD` by using a formula?

**M/D/YY Examples:**

- `12/31/17` » `2017-12-31`
- `1/1/17`  » `2017-01-01`

**D/M/YY Examples:**

- `31/12/17` » `2017-12-31`
- `1/1/17`  » `2017-01-01`

Answer (score 1):

Entire formula (including year, month, day) while referencing table cell `A1` (in this example) having the date in either `M/D/YY` or `D/M/YY`:

**`M/D/YY` to `YYYY-MM-DD`**

`"20"&RIGHT(A1;2)&"-"&IF(LEN(MID(A1;1;FIND("/";A1;1)−1))=1;"0"&MID(A1;1;FIND("/";A1;1)−1);MID(A1;1;FIND("/";A1;1)−1))&"-"&IF(LEN(MID(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)−FIND("/";A1)−1))=1;"0"&MID(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)−FIND("/";A1)−1);MID(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)−FIND("/";A1)−1))`

**`D/M/YY` to `YYYY-MM-DD`**

`"20"&RIGHT(A1;2)&"-"&IF(LEN(MID(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)−FIND("/";A1)−1))=1;"0"&MID(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)−FIND("/";A1)−1);MID(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)−FIND("/";A1)−1))&"-"&IF(LEN(MID(A1;1;FIND("/";A1;1)−1))=1;"0"&MID(A1;1;FIND("/";A1;1)−1);MID(A1;1;FIND("/";A1;1)−1))`

---

**Single fields**

For some background and to extract the individual fields:

- **Year**: `"20"&RIGHT(A1;2)`
- **First Number (Month or Day)**: `IF(LEN(MID(A1;1;FIND("/";A1;1)−1))=1;"0"&MID(A1;1;FIND("/";A1;1)−1);MID(A1;1;FIND("/";A1;1)−1))`
- **Second Number (Month or Day)**: `IF(LEN(MID(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)−FIND("/";A1)−1))=1;"0"&MID(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)−FIND("/";A1)−1);MID(A1;FIND("/";A1)+1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1)−FIND("/";A1)−1))`